# Windows 10 lock screen always shows 'Please wait' message other than correct string

Tags: windows-10, lock-screen

Windows 10 lock screen message always shows 'Please wait' instead of corresponding message (i.e 'Welcome', 'Shutting down', 'Restarting'). There are no stuck while the 'Please wait' message shows up, it's just a wrong string for message to show up.

This happened after I clicked 'I forgot PIN' option at the lock screen  when I tried to logon before. I have tried changing system language, `sfc /scannow`, but none of it worked. How do I make it show correct message in the lock screen?

Answer (score 0):

The Welcome message is found in the registry under key
`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`.

There are two parts in the items `legalnoticecaption` and `legalnoticetext`,
of which the first is the one you probably would like to change.

Use `regedit` to change `legalnoticecaption`.

It is good practice to create a System Restore point before doing any registry
modification, just in case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However those registry keys' values were already blank for me, and modifying them didn't seem to resolve the problem.

Comment: Windows changes all the time. I don't know when the above method was invalidated or if a new one is now known.